Can the slack in 2 different strings (ideal) be transferred to one another?

So, I am assuming that the string on the left side of Pulley Z and the right side of Pulley Z is different. My first doubt would be, is that assumption(1), correct?
I went with that assumption(1), and I assumed(2) that block B is moving up with a distance of 'x'. Therefore, the total slack caused by the translational motion of Pulley X in string 1 would be 2x. (String 1 being the entire string to left of Pulley Z)
Then, that slack will transfer over to the left of Pulley Z, still being 2x, since I am trying to solve the question without making Pulley Y move.
Now comes "main" doubt, would Block A have to move down by 'x', like, would the slack in the string 1 = 2x, be transferred to String 2 (right of Pulley Z)? Or would it remain in string 1? If it remains in string 1 (left of Pulley Z), then the block A would have to move by 4x, and then there would be upwards translational motion in Pulley Y by 2x, and how would the slack in the strings be affected by that?
The pulleys and the strings are ideal, basically, massless and rigid. No friction.
Assumption 1 = Are the strings different on different sides of pulley Z? Like, are there 4 strings or just 3?
Assumption 2 = I am assuming that only block B moves upward and not Pulley Y, as asked for in the question.
If I made any other assumptions without thinking about them, please inform them.
Sorry if I asked too much. This is my first question.
Also, sorry if I made any grammatical errors. I am just focusing on improving my physics.

A string going around the curved part of a pulley is continuous. There are 3 strings - two short strings from which masses A and B hang, and one long string that goes from the ceiling at the top left, around each of the 4 pulleys (little-X, Y, Z, and big-X), and connects to the center of pulley Y.

Oh, so the entire slack will be in the long string. Then block A would have to move by x. Right?

There is one continuous length of string going round all four pulleys. Let's split this into five consecutive lengths $l_1 \dots l_5$ where:

$l_1$ is the distance between the ceiling and the centre of pulley X
$l_2$ is the distance between the centre of pulley X and the centre of pulley Y
$l_3$ is the distance between the centre of pulley Y and the entre of pulley Z
$l_4$ is the distance between the centre of pulley Z and the centre of top fixed pulley
$l_5$ is the distance between the centre of the top fixed pulley and the centre of pulley Y

So we have $l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4+l_5 = L$ where $L$ is a constant length (we have not taken into account the parts of the string that wrap half way round each pulley, but since this is a constant length of string we can ignore it).
Since $l_1$ is the distance between pulley X and the ceiling, which is at a fixed height, we can see that the velocity of pulley X is $v_X = \frac {dl_1}{dt}$ where we take a downwards velocity as being positive. Similarly (since the height of the top fixed pulley is constant) we know that the velocity of pulley Y is $v_Y = \frac {dl_5}{dt}$ and the velocity of pulley Z is $v_Z =\frac {dl_4}{dt}$.
Since $l_2$ is the distance between pulley X and pulley Y, we have
$\displaystyle \frac {dl_2}{dt} = v_X - v_Y = \frac {dl_1}{dt} - \frac {dl_5}{dt}$
and also
$\displaystyle \frac {dl_3}{dt} = v_Z - v_Y = \frac {dl_4}{dt} - \frac {dl_5}{dt}$
Since we know that $L$ is a constant value, we have $\frac{dL}{dt} = 0$, so
$v_X + (v_X-v_Y) + (v_Z-v_Y) + v_Z + v_Y = 0
\\ \Rightarrow 2v_X - v_Y + 2v_Z = 0$
So if we are given any two velocities from $v_X, v_Y, v_Z$ we can find the third velocity (and note that the velocity of pulley X is the same as the velocity of block B etc.).
Differentiating the velocities relationship gives a similar relationship between the accelerations of the three pulleys. So, once again, given two accelerations we can find the third.

Wow. It all makes sense now! You took the ceiling to be the base and differentiated the simplest equation. I was trying to think of it in a very practical way and I believe I got somewhat of a similar result, intuitively. But I needed this mathematical approach too. Thank you very much for your answer!


If you cut the string you obtain the string tension $~T~$
I)  write the equations of motion
$$ m\,\ddot X=-m\,g+2\,T\\
m\,\ddot Y=-m\,g-2\,T+T\\
m\,\ddot Z=-m\,g+2\,T$$
II) obtain the tension contribution matrix
$$ \mathbf C_T=\begin{bmatrix}
  2 \\
  -1 \\
  2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
this means that the constraint equation is
$$ 2 \ddot X-\ddot Y+2\ddot Z=0\quad\text{or} \\
 2 \dot X-\dot Y+2\dot Z=0$$

for a kinematic case  all masses are zero and from the contribution matrix of the tension force  you obtain the
constraint equation
